# Is it normal for timestamp to be saved into Firestore as "timestamp"?

Tags: swift, firebase, unix-timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am saving server value timestamp as follow:

```
let data : [String: Any] = ["userId": 9,
                            "name": "Elon Musk",
                            "timeCreated": ServerValue.timestamp()]

 let doc = firestore.collection("orders").document()
 doc.setData(data){ (error) in

 }
```

When looking into Firestore, though I see this:

[image]

Is this normal? Shouldn't there be instead a long containing the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch?

Comment: What does your `ServerValue.timestamp()` function look like?

Comment: @creeperspeak, it's the same that comes with Firebase iOS SDK. `ServerValue.timestamp()` is a `[AnyHashable : Any]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using the Realtime Database notion of server timestamp, which is [ServerValue.timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRServerValue#/c:objc(cs)FIRServerValue(cm)timestamp).  It's essentially a dictionary with the values you showed: `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}`.  That's not compatible with Firestore.

Instead, you want to use Firestore's notion of server timestamp, which is [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue#servertimestamp).  Also see the very last sample in the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: How can I retrieve it from the server? I mean, if I am mapping the object from Firestore to a POJO in my Android project, for instance, what should be the type of `timeCreated`? I tried `var timeCreated: FieldValue? = null` but it didn't work since it seems FieldValue has no setter for timestamp

Comment: It'll be a number on the way out, expressed as milliseconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not seem normal.  This is what I get when I use ServerValue.timestamp().
[image]